# Is synchronization really needed in multithreading in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization

I am a little bit confused with why synchronization is needed in multithreading in python. Given the Global internal lock, there can only be one thread accessing the python object at a time right? so why do we still need synchronization library such as `queue.Queue`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because pulling an item from a list and marking it as pulled, processing it and marking it as done are no atomic operation.

Comment: More generally, to lock a data structure during multiple operations. The interpreter may even switch threads in the middle of a line of code, if that line consists of multiple operations.